# Custom XML attributes used in custom widgets

Tags: android, custom-component, custom-attribute

I am creating subclasses of various Android widgets to create my own widgets. Here is what I have done so far:

(defined in my res/values/attr.xml)

```
<attr name="font">
    <enum name="ARIAL_BOLD" value="1" />
    <enum name="ARIAL_ROUND_MT" value="2" />
    <enum name="HELVETICA" value="3" />
    <enum name="HELVETICA_BOLD" value="4" />
    <enum name="GILSANCE_LIGHT" value="4" />
  </attr>

<declare-styleable name="EditText">
    <attr name="font" />
</declare-styleable>
<declare-styleable name="Button">
    <attr name="font" />
</declare-styleable>
<declare-styleable name="TextView">
    <attr name="font" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Then in my `EditText` I use this as:

```
public class EditText extends android.widget.EditText {

    public EditText(Context context) {
        super(context);     
    }

    public EditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.EditText);
    }
}
```

Now I want to read the value of the enum that has been set in the XML code. How can I read it? Then, based on the font supplied, I want to set my custom font. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<attr name="font">
    <enum name="ARIAL_BOLD" value="1" />
    <enum name="ARIAL_ROUND_MT" value="2" />
    <enum name="HELVETICA" value="3" />
    <enum name="HELVETICA_BOLD" value="4" />
    <enum name="GILSANCE_LIGHT" value="5" />
</attr>

<declare-styleable name="CustomEditText">
    <attr name="font" />
</declare-styleable>
<declare-styleable name="CustomButton">
    <attr name="font" />
</declare-styleable>
<declare-styleable name="CustomTextView">
    <attr name="font" />
</declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

Then my custom file

```
public class CustomEditText extends android.widget.EditText {

    public CustomEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            R.styleable.CustomEditText);
        final int fontValue = a.getInt(R.styleable.CustomEditText_font, 0);
        setTypeFace(fontValue);
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            R.styleable.CustomEditText);
        final int fontValue = a.getInt(R.styleable.CustomEditText_font, 0);
        setTypeFace(fontValue);
    }

    public void setTypeFace(int fontValue) {
        Typeface myTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getContext()
            .getAssets(), getApplicationFont(fontValue));
        this.setTypeface(myTypeFace);
    }
}


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/login_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mycomp.myproj">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topBarText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/application_name"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

     <com.myapp.ui.CustomEditText
        app:font="ARIAL_ROUND_MT"
        android:id="@+id/samPLE"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/application_name"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="35sp" />
```

This worked for me. Just to note my custom views were placed in a Android Library Project.

Comment: I had tried but got stuck. When i finally got the answer, i shared it with you guys. no harm done.